# ZF2 Form: NumberFormat-filter with localization

Tags: forms, filter, localization, zend-framework2, number-formatting

hy,

how can I define the NumberFormat-filter for an input in a fieldset which is aware of the current locale? What I want is that numbers like **1000.33** are displayed in the view like this: **1.000,33** (or whatever locale is specified) I have tried it with the InputFilterProviderInterface, but it doesn't has any effect in the view:

```
<?php
namespace Customer\Form;

use Customer\Entity\OfferDay;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;

use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class OfferDayFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct($em)
    {
        parent::__construct('offerDayFieldset');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($em))
             ->setObject(new OfferDay());

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'price',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => '',
            ),
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            'price' => array(
                'required' => false,
                'filters' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'NumberFormat',
                        'options' => array(
                            'locale' => 'de_DE',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

In the view I output the input via the `formRow()`-function.

I also know that you can use the NumberFormat-Filter programmatically like this ([l18n Filters - Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.i18n.filters.html#zend-i18n-filter-number-format-usage)):

```
$filter = new \Zend\I18n\Filter\NumberFormat("de_DE");
echo $filter->filter(1234567.8912346);
// Returns "1.234.567,891"
```

but I wanna use the array-notation.

Has anybody done something like this or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok this seems not as trivial as I thought :) but I got a solution.

first define the filter like this:

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
{
    return array(
        'price' => array(
            'required' => false,
            'filters' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'NumberFormat',
                    'options' => array(
                        'locale' => 'de_DE',
                        'style' => NumberFormatter::DECIMAL,
                        'type' => NumberFormatter::TYPE_DOUBLE,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

whereas *locale* is the currently used locale. This formats the numbers into the currect format before saving it to the database.

In the view, you can use the filter view helper to convert the numbers to the right format:

```
<?php
    $this->plugin("numberformat")
         ->setFormatStyle(NumberFormatter::DECIMAL)
         ->setFormatType(NumberFormatter::TYPE_DOUBLE)
         ->setLocale("de_DE");
?>

<p>
    <?php 
        $currentElement = $form->get('price');
        $currentElement->setValue($this->numberFormat($currentElement->getValue())); 
        echo $this->formRow($currentElement);
    ?>
</p>
```

**Result:**
Database: 12.345 ->
View: 12,345 -> Database: 12.345